# C++ WinForms, get the name of a System object

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli, clr, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently learning how to make windows programs in C++ with CLR in Visual Studio 2022. I'm very new to C++ (Started 2 days ago and I barely know what a struct is), and I just can't seem to find out how I can get the name of an object (A label) on my form as a string variable to log to the developer's console.

Here's my current code:

```
    private:
        System::Void Btn1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
        {
            string label1name = label1->AccessibleName->ToString();
            string label1text = label1->Text->ToString();

            cout << "[INPUT] " << "Was pressed" << endl;
            cout << "[DEBUG] Changed " << label1name << " to " << label1text << endl;
        }
```

and here's a screenshot of my current form: [Windows form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dXT3.png)

Comment: It's just `label1->Name`. Already a string (as is `AccessibleName`).

Comment: That didn't work for me either, it would give me the error `No suitable constructor exists to convert from "System::String ^" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char, std:;allocator<char>>"`

Comment: It appears you are programming in **C++/CLI**, which is a similar-but-different programming language from **C++**.  (Much like how Objective-C++ is a similar-but-different programming language from C++.)  You ought to tag the question with `c++-cli` rather than `c++`, which will attract the attention of people experienced with that topic.

Comment: `String^ theName = label1->Name;` --  Where do you want your output to appear?

Comment: I want my output to be printed to the console, hence the `cout` expression.
Also, the expression you gave, gives the errror `'initializing' cannot convert from System::String ^ to std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'`

Comment: What Console? You have a Windows Forms app there.

Comment: I start it up with Local Windows Debugger and it logs everything to the console that appears with the form. I don't know why it's such a mystery to you that there's a console when I start it

Comment: It's not a Console, it's the Output pane. `using namespace System::Diagnostics;  /* other */ Debug::WriteLine(label1->Name);`

Comment: That doesn't seem to output anything for me. I've used `cout` in the public void MyForm

` public:
  MyForm(void)
  {
   InitializeComponent();
   cout << "[DEBUG] Program started" << endl;
  }` like so and it worked

Comment: Did you create a WIndows Forms application or a Console application that happens to show a Form?

Comment: I honestly do not remember

Comment: A WinForms app doesn't have a Console, unless you attach one in code, that is.